# \includegraphics image not displaying in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

I am trying to add an image made in inkscape to a beamer presentation as follows.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme[dark]{solarized}
\usetheme{default}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Scheme}
  \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
    \rule{100pt}{150pt}% Place your graphic here
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.6\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[resolution=91,trim={1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm},width=1\columnwidth, keepaspectratio]{ntree}
    \end{figure}
      \centering
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the pdf generated looses the image when zoomed out as shown below:

[image]

Which when zoomed out, I loose the image,

[image: d]

Is this simply a resolution problem? I've tried increasing the dpi of the inkscape graphic. What else could I do?

Comment: Welcome! Please complete your code so we can copy-paste-compile to try to reproduce the issue. It may be a viewer issue. Have you tried other viewers?

Comment: I updated things. You may be able to remove the solarized theme.

Comment: I can reproduce this in both the TeXShop preview and Mac Preview apps. You have any suggestions in another viewer?

Comment: Thanks for providing a complete document. Unfortunately, it requires an image we don't have. If you provide something we can reproduce with, people will test it on different systems with different viewers. We can't test it if it depends on the inclusion of an image we don't have, though. Can you reproduce with one of the default images `example-image-a` or similar? Or can you post the image you are including here?

Comment: Without `\usecolortheme[dark]{solarized}` and with `example-image` it wirks. Tested with MikTeX and Sumatra and Adobe Reader DC.

Comment: Viewing the document in Foxit works! So Preview has this behavior, does that mean it is a resolution problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a PDF viewer problem.